# Inequality proofs

Tags: inequality

How do I prove that $$\ln(1+t)\geq t(1-t/2), \;\forall\; t\geq 0.$$ and that $$\ln2t\leq t\ln2, \;\forall\; t\geq 2.$$ How does the latter imply $$(\ln2t)^2\leq 2t\ln2, \;\forall\; t\geq 2.$$

Comment: That first one isn't an inequality, and it's false...is that a typo?

Comment: @Ataraxia, it's a typo, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- Let $f(t) = \ln(1+t)$ and $g(t) = t(1-\frac{t}{2})$. Try showing $f(0) \geq g(0)$ and that $f'(t) \geq g'(t)$ for all $t \geq 0$.
- For the second one, try showing that $2t \leq 2^{t}$ for all $t \geq 2$.
- For the third one, try the same principle as the first. Let $f(t) = (\ln(2t))^{2}$ and $g(t) = 2t\ln(2)$. Show that $f(2) \leq g(2)$, and then differentiate. Then use the second inequality to imply that $f'(t) \leq g'(t)$ for all $t \geq 2$.

Comment: so if $f'(t)\geq g'(t)$ for all $t\geq 0$ then $f(t)\geq g(t)$?

Comment: Yes, for all $t \geq 0$ provided that $f(0) \geq g(0)$.

Comment: could provide proof for that as well or pointer to the proof.

Comment: @Vaolter sure. It's an elementary fact from analysis that if $m(x) \geq n(x)$ for all $x \in [a, b]$, then $\int_{a}^{b} m(x)dx \geq \int_{a}^{b} n(x)dx$. Apply with $f'(t), g'(t)$ on $[0, t]$. We then have $\int_{0}^{t} f'(t) dt \geq \int_{0}^{t} g'(t)dt$, or $f(t) - f(0) \geq g(t) - g(0)$. Hence, we have $f(t) - (f(0) -g(0)) \geq g(t)$, and since $f(0) \geq g(0)$, we have $f(0) - g(0) \leq 0$, so $g(t) \leq f(t) - (f(0)-g(0)) \leq f(t)$.

Answer (score 2):

All 3 questions are applications of the derivative:

1) 
f(t) = ln (1+t) - t(1-t/2)

f '(t) = $\frac{1}{1+t} - (1-t) = \frac{t^2}{1+t} \ge 0$ when $t \ge0$, so f is increasing in the interval $[0,\infty)$, so $f(t) \ge f(0) =0$ for all t>=0

2) $\ln 2t \le t \ln 2 \ \forall\ t \ge 2$

Let f(t) = ln 2t - t ln 2, do the same as 1)

3) $(\ln (2t))^2 \le 2t \ln 2$

Let f(t) = $(\ln 2t)^2 - 2t \ln 2$.

Using 2) to conclude  $f'(t) \le 0 \ \forall\ t \ge 2$, so f is decreasing in the interval $[2, \infty)$, so $f(t) \le f(2) =0$. Done.